# Install .APK from Android Cache

Tags: android, caching, save, apk, internal

I have problems installing an APK saved in Android internal Cache. 
There are no issues saving the file in External Storage or on External Cache using **context.getExternalCacheDir()**.

But if I try to use **context.getCacheDir()**, the log returns

***/data/data/com.my.package/cache/update.apk: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)***

```
                File file = context.getCacheDir();

                File outputFile = new File(file, "update.apk");
                if(outputFile.exists()){
                    outputFile.delete();
                }

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);


                InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len1 = 0;
                while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                }
                fos.close();
                is.close();

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                //SAVE IN CACHE
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(outputFile), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // without this flag android returned a intent error!
                context.startActivity(intent);
```

It looks like internal cache doesn't allow the APK to be correctly read.

The fact is, if the file is saved on the External Storage or external Cache the APK will be available to the user, and I don't want that.

What can it be don to save the file in internal Cache?

Thanks

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8784822/6056489

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It looks like internal cache doesn't allow the APK to be correctly read.

That is because the installer app has no rights to read your file.

> The fact is, if the file is saved on the External Storage or external Cache the APK will be available to the user, and I don't want that.

Then do not install it on the user's device. Any user can copy any APK off their device at any time after installation, so the only way to prevent the user from accessing the APK is to not have it on the device in the first place.

> What can it be don to save the file in internal Cache?

Probably nothing. If you switch to `openFileOutput()`, you can see if `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` will be sufficient for the installer to proceed. Again, this will not stop the user from being able to access the APK file.

Comment: But I see that Google Play uses internal Cache to save .apks, so I assume it's possible in some way.

"The fact is, if the file is saved on the External Storage or external Cache the APK will be available to the user, and I don't want that." Saying this, I meant that I don't want to have the .APK to be plain visible on external storage of even unrooted devices, but it's obvious that the apk has to be stored somewhere in order to install it..

Comment: @Mariux: Bear in mind that Google Play is part of the operating system, and your app is not.

Comment: If I want to use the Internal Storage approach, how can I read a file from it?

Comment: @Mariux: `openFileInput()`, or `getFilesDir()`, as you see fit.

Comment: Got it to work this way, thanks CommonsWare! Do you think that using internal storage is a good approach?

Comment: @Mariux: There is nothing particularly wrong with the approach, if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look chmod command to get read\write permissions on internal folder... As for linux it looks like...

```
 chmod 777 /data/data/*** or chmod 644 /data/data/***
```

Comment: At best, this can only be done on a rooted device, and is not an especially bright idea, for security reasons.