# How can i change the permission of my apk to -rw -rw rw- , and install it?

Tags: android, installation, apk, file-permissions

i am sending data from server to my tablet an apk file and which i will install it with this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

i have the following error : error parse , i want to change the permission to my apk file like this -rw -rw rw- ?.

Comment: see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784404/download-and-install-an-application-apk-from-internal-memory-no-sd-card

Comment: `error parse`. Is that all? Your code looks ok but it does not need that FLAG_.... Why do you want to change file permissions?

Comment: because i install it from /data/data/com.so.and/app.apk ,  i have de folowing erreur prase error there was a problem prasing the package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Chmod {
    public static void lancer() {

    String[] args2 = { "chmod", "604", "/data/data/com.so.and/sofiane.apk" };
    exec(args2);
}
    public static String exec(String[] args) {
        String result = "";
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(args);
        Process process = null;
        InputStream errIs = null;
        InputStream inIs = null;
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int read = -1;
            process = processBuilder.start();
            errIs = process.getErrorStream();
            while ((read = errIs.read()) != -1) {
                baos.write(read);
            }
            baos.write('\n');
            inIs = process.getInputStream();
            while ((read = inIs.read()) != -1) {
                baos.write(read);
            }
            byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
            result = new String(data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (errIs != null) {
                    errIs.close();
                }
                if (inIs != null) {
                    inIs.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (process != null) {
                process.destroy();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```